# mute video volume at start up in adobe flash actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How do I have the volume muted in a video when it starts or is there a code for a video volume to be muted at start up in Adobe Flash Actionscript 3?

Comment: It's according to your video player, so what's kind of player are you using ( NetStream, FLVPlayback, ... ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var video:Video = new Video(320,240);
video.volume(0);
```